# Spring manual register?

Tags: java, spring

```java
@Bean
  public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
      .readFrom(SLAVE_PREFERRED)
      .build();

    RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("server", 6379);

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig, clientConfig);
  }
```

Above, the beans are registered as annotations.

How do You register beans manually by writing code?

Comment: Seems like a XY problem. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Dynamically inject beans, and the bean name can be specified

Comment: As mentioned above, how do I change this to beanDefinition via annotation injection?